# When doing a Process.Start() do you need to wrap it in a using?

Tags: .net, process, idisposable

When you are starting a process and dont care about the result is this ok?

```
Process.Start(xxx);
```

Or should you do this

```
using (Process.Start(xxx)){}
```

Comment: Note that it's generally in poor taste to use abbreviations like `u`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of the `Process.dispose(bool)` method shows that it calls `Close()` on the `Process` instance. This in turn cleans up the native process handle so its probably not a bad idea.

It also cleans up a wait handle that it uses to check if the process has exited.

Even if you don't use the `using (...)` block the finalizer will catch these resources in the end.

Answer (score 3):

The `Process` object that is returned by `Process.Start` contains a Windows process `HANDLE`, so it should be disposed once you no longer need to use the `Process` object.

If you don't need to use the returned `Process` object at all, then the empty `using` block that you show is fine. Note that disposing the `Process` releases the handle but it (fortunately) does not stop the process from executing.